# Git: "The system cannot find the path specified." after git lfs migrate

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I'm trying to migrate an older git repo to use lfs. I previously succesfully migrated the png images to lfs, using `git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.png"` (I thought png were to only large binary files in the repo).

Now I noticed there were also an xcf source files in there still. So I tried migrating that using `git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.xcf"`.

However, when I now try to `git push -f` to update it, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Pablo\Dev\war-systems> git push -f
open C:\Users\Pablo\Dev\war-systems\Unity - War Systems\Assets\Plugins\badpix\message-16-help.png: The system cannot find the path specified.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/TheOddler/war-systems.git'
```

The file `message-16-help.png` is and old file that was deleted at some point in development. It's not in the `HEAD`, but at some point it was.

Why does this happen now? And how do I fix it?

If it matters, I'm trying to push to gitlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message (which will be improved in Git LFS 2.7.0) means that you're lacking all of the LFS objects you need to push. If you're missing an LFS object, Git LFS will try to find the file in the current working directory in order to include it, in hopes that it's still there. In this case, it's not.

You should try to find the missing `.png` file by running `git lfs fetch --all` and then try your push again. If that doesn't work, your repository is corrupt and you're missing data. You can try to do the import again with all the paths specified, or you can run your push with `GIT_TRACE=1` and find the missing object in the output, and copy it over from another repository, if you have one.

Comment: That makes sense. The solution of first doing get `fetch --all` worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Some of us would rather avoid `git lfs fetch --all` (likely because we've got limited disk space and we're working with a richly historied large repository).

I was tipped off on an easy way around this error, thanks to a year-old Slack post from a coworker.

> The file `message-16-help.png` is and old file that was deleted at some
> point in development. It's not in the HEAD, but at some point it was.

In our experience, when the file in question not a file that one would otherwise expect to be present, Git doesn't appear to need more than an empty file in that spot.

```
> touch message-16-help.png
```

...should suffice.